# How to use particular room data on crossdomain server using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, cross-domain

I'm using socket io to communicate the cross domain server and also passing the particular data, but i want to use the data on particular room on crossdomain

Here is my code

```
server side
io.emit('sendData', data);

Cross domain serverside
var socket = io('https://localhost:3000/', { transports: ['websocket'] });

socket.on('sendData', function (data) {
    console.log(data);

})
```

How to solve this? Someone please help to solve this issue

Comment: How is `cross-domain` related here? It should work the same

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible to use particular room data on a cross-domain server using socket.io
you only emit the data globally using `io.emit()`, only solution for compare your emit data with a cross-domain data